# How to work with the Microsoft Cognitive Services - Speaker Recognition API

Tags: jquery, voice-recognition, speaker

I am completely new to the Microsoft Cognitive Services. I want to build a webproject which is completely speech controlled. For the speech control I am using arytom.js, which is a very simple and great API for my usage. It works fine for me, for TTS and STT. What I want to do now is, I want to recognize who is speaking and compare it to a database. I just found the Speaker Recognition API developped by Microsoft. I have already got an API Key and now I want to create the enrollment and compare a recorded voice sample to my voice stored on the Micrososft servers.
The code sample of the official API looks like the following:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "shortAudio": "{boolean}",
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/identify?identificationProfileIds={identificationProfileIds}&" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{subscription key}");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

According to Micrososft "shortAudio" : In the case you wish to start identification using any amount of speech time, you should include the "shortAudio" parameter. It instructs the service to waive the recommended 30 seconds of audio needed to do identification. When doing so you can send audio files starting 1-second-long but no longer than 5 minutes.

I have an "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key, which I have to put in the Header, but how can I send an .wav file to their server.
Does anyone know, how to get started with this API. Unfortunately Microsoft has no real doc about it.

Update: Now I know, that I have to convert the .wav file to binary. Does someone have an example code, how to use this API to make calls?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does nobody have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am into a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

The binary data needs to be a WAV file of a specific format:

- Container: WAV
- Encoding: PCM
- Rate: 16K
- Sample Format: 16 bit
- Channels: Mono

You can check out a working example web page over here - I've used an altered copy of recorderjs (altered by reverse engineering the Speaker Recognition API examples page) to get the right bit rate and sample rate WAV:

https://rposbo.github.io/speaker-recognition-api/

Comment: how to set data: "{body}" tag in javascript

Comment: The "{body}"  is the encoded audio object. If you were using `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();` then the body would be set when you call `request.send(yourEncodedAudioObject)`.